# Link Two Tables In PowerApps

Tags: datatables, powerapps

I am trying to link three tables in PowerApps based on a field called EntName.  The demographics and Individual Notes will have a single line item (or none) for each Name, and Skills will have multiple lines per EntName.  I am trying to get to the point where I can have a single Detailed Screen that shows everything about an individual (e.g. Kevin is from Boston, ____ notes, and is skilled in Excel and PowerPoint).

The idea is that users will be able to add in notes about each individual.  The reason why tables are separated is that my Demographics are pulled (looking for new people or updates) on a daily basis and I don't want to wipe away the Notes logged previously.

Table 1: Demographics
Table 2: Individual Notes
Table 3: Skills

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: How do I make these two tables talk in PowerApps?  I'd like to be able to click into one of the Individuals in the gallery, view their information, and be able to update Notes (which goes into a second table).  But whenever I include a second table, I get errors.